# Firefox Add-ons, How to execute javascript function onLoad?

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox-addon, xul

I'm new to Firefox Add-ons. I want to create a simple Firefox add-ons that append HTML element to a page automatically on document Load. Honestly, I want to add additional BBCODE/smiley toolbar to the any existing textarea.

I got an example of xul (xml) file:

```
  <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
  <!-- some code here -->
 </popup> 



 <!-- toolbar button -->
 <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <!-- some code here -->
 </toolbarpalette>

 <!-- keyboard shortcut -->
 <keyset>
  <!-- some code here -->
 </keyset>
```

Is that easy to create a toolbar, popup menu or keyboard shortcut using script above.

The thing i just want to know is, what is the XML code to execute javasript function automatically on page load (without execute command from popup, toolbar or keyboard shortcut)???

I hope you understand with my question and everyone who help me i say thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XUL file, you just put a `<script>` tag inside your `<overlay>` tag:

```
<overlay xmlns=...>
 ... other tags here ...
 <script type="application/x-javascript" src="your_script.js"/>
</overlay>
```

Then inside `your_script.js`, you can execute whatever Javascript you want.

Here is [the MDC tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) on handling `load` events.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the 'onload' event.  See [this response to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983654/firefox-extension-how-to-catch-onload-event/1990281#1990281).