# How do I dynamically add a div element to any page from a Firefox extension/Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, overlay

I am writing an extension for firefox which will be used to annotate pages on the web via a service. I would like to have a div or an overlay element (probably XUL based) at the bottom of the page which will let people annotate a page and save it. Something like what the Google Friend Connect does on [this page](http://www.squidoo.com/websites_using_google_friend_connect), but via an addon.

This floating div/overlay should show up for every page on FF and should render contents from a web service. How do I start building this out?

If it is possible to access DOM via a FF plugin and alter it, then I would like to be able to add a floating div to the body of the document. But that doesn't work either. Example posted here: [Dynamically adding a floating div to a page](http://jsbin.com/idoli4/5)

Comment: You can add floating divs with firebug. But for what you need, I guess you would want an API through which you could do this programatically. I don't know if firebug supports that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you have to do:

1. You probably want to add some custom CSS to style the div. You can use the [*stylesheet service*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service).
2. You have to attach an event handler to the `load` event ( or `DOMContentLoaded`), to be notified when a page finished loading. Have a look at [*Intercepting Page Loads*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads) and [*On page load*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load).
3. You need a reference to element you want the new element append to. [*Tabbed Browser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) provides some useful information. E.g. you can get a reference to the `body` of the current selected tab `gBrowser.contentDocument.body`.

Regarding your code example: You forgot the give the element the CSS property `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` (you have a typo in your code, you wrote `postion`), depending on whether it should appear at the bottom of the page or the screen.

Comment: Damn! Imagine realizing a typo after a question on SO. But thanks for all the other suggestions.

Comment: @Felix Kling Can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983654/firefox-extension-how-to-catch-onload-event

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (because I have).  To do it you'll need to find the node you want to change the content of (if you're adding to the bottom of the page, you may want to use the <body> node I guess) and then call one of:

```
 insertBefore(theNewNode, afterThisNode);
 insertAfter(theNewNode, thisNode);
```

Or possibly, but I'm not sure:

```
 anExistingNode.innerHTML = anExistingNode.innerHTML + myNewContent;
```

That should be enough to get you started.