# login to my drupal-website via my firefox-addon

Tags: drupal, authentication, popup, firefox-addon

I'm working on a FF-extension, that displays user-specific information on 3rd-party websites. Users need to be logged in to my Drupal-website. I'm checking login state with a cross-domain-proof jQuery.ajax(). If a user is not logged in, the FF-extension opens a popup-window (window.open()) showing a Drupal login/register/passwordlost page (/user/login).

Now I would like this window to close and the FF-extension to carry on, as soon as the login (registration/password-request) is successful. And now I'm lost… How would I do this?

I know how to close the popup from my FF-addon (window.close()), but I don't know how to tell the addon, when to do it. I thought of polling the login-state. But that seems kind of clumsy, no? 
I have also tried redirecting the drupal-page after successful login (login destination module) to a self-closing page, but in newer browsers window.close() works only on windows, that were created with the same script. And then I would still have to find a way to tell the FF-addon to proceed.

How do other people solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think drupal.stackexchange.com will be the place to ask this question as it is more related to FF-extension than to Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't knwon about Firefox extension, but you can probably listen to `onload` event on your popup `window` to detect a new page load. If the destination page for successful login contains some flag reachable from your extension, you can then query for this flag from your `onload` handler.

Catching onload from your extension seems doable, see [firefox extension. How to catch onload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983654/firefox-extension-how-to-catch-onload-event)

Comment: The documentation on onload and ff-extensions seems to provide lots of learning opportunities for me. So I decided to stick with polling for now. Thanks anyway.